User Licenses concern
Just a simple question. My boss would like to maximize all of the licenses available in our org. I told him that the Salesforce license is the only thing we just need to use for our users and some admins. However, he's asking about these 3 licenses which I don't know how to explain:

Can you give me some insights that I can share to my boss so we'll fully understand the use of these licenses? Thank you!

Analytics Cloud Integration User: provides the permissions necessary to integrate with CRM Analytics. You can read more in Best Practices: Manage Integration and Security Users in CRM Analytics. Note that these licenses are not for you to use, but to enable CRM Analytics to work correctly. They do not count against your Salesforce licenses or any other licenses you pay for.
Sales Insights Integration User: provides the permissions necessary to integrate with Sales Insights. I could not find much information on this in the documentation, but this Known Issue titled Not able to deactivate or remove the Sales Insights Integration User and profile explains that this profile is for a connection between your Salesforce org and the Einstein infrastructure, and provides access to the Sales Cloud Einstein. It is not for your organization's direct use. These do not use your Salesforce licenses or other licenses you pay for.
Salesforce Integration: Described in Assign the New Salesforce Integration User License to Grant API Only Access, this license is provided as a free license to allow dedicated users for integrations. Unlike a normal user, this user cannot log in to the UI, and is intended for API connections from third-party sources to provide integration between Salesforce and external systems. Additional licenses can be purchased if you need more than your organization has allocated. These cannot be used as normal user licenses, and do not count against your Salesforce licenses or any other licenses you pay for.
